# Connection error using SUSE/Windows with VMware

Tags: vmware, suse, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to run a SUSE Linux VM in a Windows 10 host using VMware Workstation 12 Player. I set up a `host-only` connection between Linux and Windows with a static IP in Linux. Problem is that the connection does not work, I try to ping from Windows but the request gets timed out. WMware created the following network adapter:

[image]

And this is the Linux `ifconfig`, including the static IP:

[image]

What's wrong with this configuration? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let set VM machine IP to same subnet with your VMnet interface (192.168.174.0/24)

Example:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.174.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

and ping again...

Goodluck.